# Any tips on making this long piece-wise function look better/more space in cases?

Tags: equations, amsmath, cases

[image]

I managed to make it work, but ideally I would like to input all the constants I've denoted as letters with their values (makes it more like an actual function), unfortunately, I already don't have much space as it is (the top equation really skews everything to the right), and the equation label isn't in line (overfull). Any tips?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    W(h) = 
      \begin{cases} 
       \biggl[MM_r\times \frac{6.1121\exp[(18.678 - \frac{T_0-6.5\times h_{km}}{234.5})(\frac{T_0-6.5\times h_{km}}{257.14 + (T_0-6.5\times h_{km})})]\times 100}{287.04 (288.15 - 6.5\times h_{km} )} \biggl]  \times 1000 \times \frac{AvC}{MM_w} & 0\leq h<11000 \\
       9.92302545521\times 10^{20} & 11000\leq h<21000\\
       \biggl[MM_r\times \frac {6.1121\exp[(18.678 - \frac{T_{21}}{234.5})(\frac{T_{21}}{257.14 + T_{21}})]\times 100}{R_a(0.001h-76.5)}\biggl] \times 1000 \times \frac{AvC}{MM_w} & 21000\leq h<32000
   \end{cases} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Edited equations:
[image: edited]

Comment: It would probably be better to use some `to ease notation we define ...` to define some of these parts separately and then  write those instead of the full expressions. Note that `\bigg` is way to large for the denominator in the first row, I'd not even scale () there.

Comment: as dalef says just use () in the denominator, I'd be tempted to replace h/1000 by h' (or anything) throughout so you don't have nested fractions and use `\\[5pt]` or whatever looks right to have more space between the cases. (As always a complete document would be easier to test than a fragment, apart from anything else it would confirm the text width)

Comment: Another reason to use the `to ease notation` is to convert these very not userfriendly `e^{...}` to `\exp(....)` which should be a lot more readable

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I've done what you suggested, however, check my updated post to see how it looks like. It's more readable, but it takes up way too much horizontal width, in terms of font, I'm not sure making anything smaller would help the readability factor. My document uses default settings for font.

Comment: That is not what we meant, and as David mentions, please always make these examples a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. See this discusseion for details https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I've updated my code as a minimal example. I've included all the packages I've used that might be impacting formatting.

Comment: I would say this would look better if you took out the numbers and used more letters.  I'm having trouble seeing how W changes with h because there's so much stuff in the way.  Not to mention that the first two branches are constant (or are we supposed to know that `h_{km}=h/1000`?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only try to realize what daleif and David already pointed out in comments: remove unnecessary large braces, and introduce abbreviations for repeated expressions. For example, the arguments of the exponential are basically the same expression evaluated at two different values, so introduce a function for it. Something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% for {dcases} (loads amsmath)
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{27}
\ldots\ and we find the following appalling expression
\begin{equation}
    W(h) = 
      \begin{dcases} 
       M M_r\times \frac{6.1121\exp\{f(T_0-h')\}\times 100}{287.04 (288.15 - h')} \times \varphi, & 0\leq h<11000 \\[1ex]
       9.92302545521\times 10^{20}, & 11000\leq h<21000\\[1ex]
       M M_r\times \frac{6.1121\exp\{f(T_{21})\}\times 100}{R_a(0.001h-76.5)} \times \varphi, & 21000\leq h<32000
   \end{dcases} 
\end{equation}
where
$
 \begin{aligned}[t]
 f(x)    &= \biggl(18.678 - \frac{x}{234.5}\biggr) \frac{x}{257.14+x} \\
 h'      &= 6.5 h / 1000 \\
 \varphi &= 1000 \times \frac{AvC}{M M_w}
 \end{aligned}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other improvements are certainly conceivable. For example, `6.1121` times `100` could be just `611.21` (unless you have some particular reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge: since it's troublesome to cram all of those symbols into the cases, don't try to cram all of those symbols into the cases!

[image: typeset math]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Set
\begin{align*}
    W_1(h) &= \biggl[MM_r\times \frac{6.1121\exp[(18.678 - \frac{T_0-6.5\times h_{km}}{234.5})(\frac{T_0-6.5\times h_{km}}{257.14 + (T_0-6.5\times h_{km})})]\times 100}{287.04 (288.15 - 6.5\times h_{km} )} \biggl]  \times 1000 \times \frac{AvC}{MM_w} \\
    W_2(h) &= \biggl[MM_r\times \frac {6.1121\exp[(18.678 - \frac{T_{21}}{234.5})(\frac{T_{21}}{257.14 + T_{21}})]\times 100}{R_a(0.001h-76.5)}\biggl] \times 1000 \times \frac{AvC}{MM_w},
\end{align*}
and then define
\begin{equation}
    W(h) = 
      \begin{cases} 
       W_1(h), & \text{if } 0\leq h<11000, \\
       9.92302545521\times 10^{20}, & \text{if } 11000\leq h<21000, \\
       W_2(h), & \text{if } 21000\leq h<32000.
   \end{cases} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar idea of presenting, like some others here showed already. But may be I'd go even a step further.

As a reader I want to "get it at a glance", and don't want to dive into each and every formula. So, here's a way to do it:

1. Split, as already mentioned the one big formula into

- a simplified version (S) of it
- 3 extra-lines with the required definitions (D1 .. D3)
- that's what was already mentioned.

2. Single out common AND non-common parts in D1 .. D3. E.g. for the first D1 and third D3 there are a lot of common factors: subsummize those, unless it's there for a certain didactical reason. This might even include transforming `6.1121\exp[(18.678]` into an individual constant, if that makes the structure even more self-evident.

This way there is a kind of hierarchie, which makes clear the 3 cases w.r.t. h, commonaliteis, if any, and differences, all at a glance.